# App shows error on new device (lollipop) but works fine on my old device (kitkat)

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, google-maps-markers

i am facing a very unusual error (at list for me cause i am new in programming) i have developed an app in which mainActivity has facebook login then it goes to MapsActivity.App crashes in any new lollipop device but works fine in my old kitkat device.here is my activity code and MapsActivity.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp, PID: 31999
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp/com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2176)
  at com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:99)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2176) 
  at com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:99) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2176) 
  at com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:99) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
```

Here is my MapsActivity -

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

public GoogleMap mMap;
private HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
private BufferedReader reader = null;
private String forecastJsonStr = null;
private  String url = "My_url";




// menu bar option enable

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map,menu);
    return true;
}

// on menu click

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.Exit){
        finish();
        System.exit(0);


        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.Logout){
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }



    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


public void onMapSearch (View view) throws IOException {

    //hide button when button is pressed
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    //preview the entered address as an Tost in bar
    EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();

    //this will animate camera and zoom 12.0f
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f));



    //further address search codes
    List<Address> addressList = null;

    //if nothing will be entered in the edit-text will not show a toast rather than crashing of thekha app
    if (locationSearch.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter an Address",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {

        //process of exception handling and finding location
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            //if address is greater than one then these processes will happen

            if(addressList.size()>0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(location + " is Here ")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                Toast.makeText(this, location+" is here, Zoom In or Zoom Out to make your Thekha Visible ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show(); //popup type to show entered data
            }
            else {
                //process where entered entry will not gonna find , this will gonna a toast to show popup

                Toast.makeText(this,"Entered Address Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }
}
ProgressDialog pd = null;

private class RetriveMarkerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private Context context;


    public RetriveMarkerTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please wait ...");
        pd.setMessage("Connecting to Loofre Network");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... markerGetUrl) {
        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url1 = new URL(url);

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            forecastJsonStr = "Error, an exception was raised.";
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return forecastJsonStr;

    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String markers) {


        Log.d("string response",markers);

        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Plotting Thekha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(markers);
            for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                //create marker of each place in the json data
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String placeAddress = jsonObject.getString("address");
                double latitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(0);
                double longitude = jsonObject.getJSONArray("latlang").getDouble(1);
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                //marker size change code
                int height = 150;
                int width =150;
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable =(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thekhaicon);
                Bitmap b=bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                Bitmap smallMarker =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,width,height,false);
                //marker size change code ends here
                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 13));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))
                        .title(placeName)
                        .snippet(placeAddress)
                        .position(loc)

                );

                LatLng dwarka = new LatLng(28.570317,77.32182);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dwarka, 13));
                mMap.addMarker(
                        new MarkerOptions()
                                .title("Wine Beer Liquor Shop, Sector 18, Noida")
                                .snippet("Sector 18, Near Centre Stage Mall, Noida")
                                .position(dwarka));
            }
            pd.dismiss();
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}


//OnReady map starts here when we can enter or add Marker to the map
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {





    Toast.makeText(this, "Connecting Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        RetriveMarkerTask markerTask = new RetriveMarkerTask(MapsActivity.this);
        markerTask.execute(url);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Can not fetch data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //  int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    }
    //tool bar and other tool related on map uiSettings
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

here is my MapsActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#3f51b5">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:hint="@string/enter_address"
        android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
        tools:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal" />


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="onMapSearch"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:background="@drawable/search_button" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="522dp"
tools:context="com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity" />
```

---

```
MAnifest file : -
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSWEVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="MY THEKHA"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="MYTHEKHA"
        />
    <activity
        android:name=".instructionSlide"
        android:label="MY THEKHA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:label="My Thekha" />
</application>
```

Syles.xml -

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: You have two top-level elements in MapsActivity.xml?

Comment: i can't understand what you mean ... This is all of my code sir

Comment: @MikeM. sir can you help me with this ?

Comment: There is problem on **Button** style this line      style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall".

Comment: @NitinKarande Sir how can i fix this ?

Comment: remove this style from `Button` `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"` and check what happen ?

Comment: @Ironman Still crashes i don't know what is happening

Comment: add ur manifest file @kuldeepraj

Comment: @NitinKarande dude can you help me with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795136/plot-a-marker-on-current-location-after-async-task-onpostexecution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
    android:hint="@string/enter_address"
    android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
   />
  //add this to your Manifest.xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

style could be the problem.

Comment: i cannot access these type of urls from my place.can you paste it?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp, PID: 11520
java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
at maps.ad.t.c(Unknown Source)
at xj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:274)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
at gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
at thekhagpsnavigation.newthekhaapp.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:335)

Comment: please try my answer now

Comment: did you get any result?

Comment: Yes .... i had to comment out mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
but it Disabled the location button

Comment: Check my answer add to your code and uncomment mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: bro i have already uncommented that one and perviously i have those user permission in my manifest file.. now there are two issues. 1. My location button is gone. 2.Title Bar is gone .. When i am trying to add a theme in manifest file for mapActivity app again crashes. and other activities have Title bar

Comment: what is the theme you are adding?

Comment: theme.AppCompat or anything no matter what theme i add it crashes ... When i remove Theme it works fine

Comment: Theme.AppCompat is working fine.. Sorry .. how how can i enable titile bar bro ...cause i have to set action bar and navigation drawer

Comment: try to create a new project and choose NavigationDrawer Activity in templatesYou can take it as a reference.and try

Comment: i cant fix this one ... it was a really long road for me

Comment: dude can you help me with this question ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795136/plot-a-marker-on-current-location-after-async-task-onpostexecution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129012/discussion-between-rushi-ayyappa-and-kuldeep-raj).